# Java Run another class with a JButton

Tags: java, swing, acm-java-libraries

```
public class SocialNetwork extends Program 
                implements Constants {

  Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

  public void init() {

    breakoutButton = new JButton("Play Breakout Game");
    breakoutButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    breakoutButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    add(breakoutButton, WEST);
    breakoutButton.addActionListener(this);

   getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

   addActionListeners();

   add(canvas);
  }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Play Breakout Game") || e.getSource() ==   breakoutButton) {

    canvas.displayMessage("game started"); //displayMessage method displays the parameter string on the canvas.
    Breakout bo = new Breakout();
    bo.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

This is the main code which creates the button which is supposed to launch the breakout game. The code for breakout is :

```
public class Breakout extends GraphicsProgram {

    public void run() {

      setBackground(Color.BLACK);

      setUpBricks();

      points = new GLabel("Points: " + pointsCounter);
      add(points, getWidth()/2 - points.getWidth()/2, getHeight() - points.getAscent());
      points.setColor(Color.WHITE);

      for(int i=0; i < NTURNS; i++) {
        addMouseListeners();
        setUpGame(); 
        playGame();
        if (brickCounter == 0) {
          GLabel winner = new GLabel("You Win! You got " + pointsCounter + " points.");
          winner.setFont("Times New Roman-25");
          winner.setColor(Color.WHITE);
          add(winner, getWidth()/2 - winner.getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2 - winner.getAscent()/2);
          break;
        } 
      } 
      if (ball.getY() > getHeight()) { 
        GLabel message = new GLabel("Game Over! You got " + pointsCounter + " points.");
        message.setFont("Times New Roman-25");
        message.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        add(message, getWidth()/2 - message.getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2 - message.getAscent()/2);
       }
   }
```

The problem is that when I click on the button, it registers the click, opens a JFrame, but does not run the program. There is just a blank JFrame. What am I doing wrong?
Note: I have only posted the basic code for the breakout game part.

Comment: Do you intend to run a `JFrame` (e.g. `Breakout`) or a `GraphicsProgram` (e.g. `BreakoutGame`)? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - now I notice both [`GraphicsProgram`](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html) & [`Program`](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/Program.html) are instances of `JApplet`, it just underlines how useless & obsolete the ACM Java API is. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates the `Breakout` object and sets its visibility:

```
Breakout bo = new Breakout();
bo.setVisible(true);
```

However, you never invoke any other methods. For example you may want to invoke a `run` method or a `main` method. You have to call those methods somehow in order to execute the code.

Another option would be to add a listener to the `Breakout` class so that it executes your code when the window opens, something like this:

```
addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            //call a method that runs the program here!
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried invoking the run method by doing bo.run(). Same thing happening.

Comment: You have a class within a class so it's not clear from the code in your post how it should be run.

Comment: I changed the class so that it only extends GraphicsProgram. What about now?

Comment: Given the modified code in your post, calling `bo.run();` as you mentioned in the above comment should execute your code inside the `run` method because `Breakout` now has a `run` method.